# Ocultar "<div>" PopUp usando Cookie

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Tenho um web site o qual exibe um vídeo de boas vindas, quero ocultar uma div o qual é um PopUp que criei o qual exibe o vídeo, quero ocultar esta div usando cookie para que ele não apareça novamente e não atrapalhe sempre que o usuário entrar. preciso ajuda com a logica e se possível algum exemplo de código que talvez funcione.

```
<div id="popup_this" class="popup">
<!-- O video vai aqui -->
</div>
```

Este é o código da div a qual não quero mostrar, toda a logica por trás do PopUp funciona mas exibir ele toda vez que o usuário entrar será chato.

Comment: Procure sobre localStorage

Comment: muito Obrigado pela ajuda pessoal